# Getting relative addresses in Excel Interop

Tags: excel-interop, range

In C# programs using the Excel Interop library,

the `Range.get_Address(...)` method seems to return a relative address `only` if R1C1 format is specified.   Does the library provide a simple way to get relative A1-style addresses?

Answer (score 1):

There's no one-liner as far as I know, but the following code should return the answer you're looking for:

```
        Range rng1 = app.get_Range("C3");
        Range rng2 = app.get_Range("D10");

        string relativeAddress = rng2.get_Offset(-1, -1).get_Address(RowAbsolute:false, ColumnAbsolute:false, ReferenceStyle:XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, RelativeTo: rng1);
        string s = app.ConvertFormula(relativeAddress, XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, false);
```